# Redirect/hide output of called program

Tags: java, stdout

This question is pretty easy I guess but I can't figure out, how to do it best. I have a JAR file which I use in my program and basically I just call the main() method of one of the classes in this JAR file.
The problem is, that I don't want to have the output of this method on my program's output - it should be hidden.

I call the method just that way:

`Main.main(new String[] {"some-arg1", "arg2", "some-argument3"});`

Is there any possibility to hide/redirect the output of this method? Can I just set a new temporary stdout or something like that?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you are looking for the `System.setOut()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.setOut()` to redirect stdout. You can also close `System.out` completely if you want to.

Comment: Thank you, I guess that's what I need. But to where should I redirect the output for hiding the prints of the other class? Is there something like /dev/null stream? Or should I just implement my own null stream?

Comment: If you just want to suppress all output, close the stream.

Comment: But I need the stream again afterwards. I want to use it before that call, then suppress it, then use it again. I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: Agh, nevermind, it wants a `PrintStream`, a legacy class. You can use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to create a `PrintStream`, then just discard those when you're done.

Comment: Nice, thank you! I did that now: `PrintStream stdout = System.out;
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));` - then I can restore the old stream afterwards! Thanks again!